# jQuery parseInt() results in NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Problem Summary

I have been working on adding up various numbers in fields, based on the `value` of input boxes. I am currently experiencing the issue in which jQuery is concatenating the `value` arguments as they are strings and I have been unable to successfully convert them to integers.

### Further Description

Here is an example of the HTML I am using:

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="one" value="20.00" />
 <input type="text" id="two" value="10.00" />
 <a href="#" id="add">
  Add up fields
 </a>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery (this behavior described above was to be expected with this script):

```
$(function(){
  var one = $('#one').val(),
      two = $('#two').val();

  $('#add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var three = one + two;
    alert(three);
  });
});
```

This resulted obviously in the output:

```
20.0010.00
```

So  I tried modifying my first variable declarions with `parseInt()` like so:

```
var one = parseInt($('#one').val(),10),
    two = parseInt($('#two').val(),10);
```

Nowever that just resulted in:

```
NaN
```

so I tried first obtaining the values and *then converting to integers*:

```
var one = $('#one').val(),
    two = $('#two').val(),
    i_one = parseInt(one),
    i_two = parseInt(two);
```

But yet agan... `NaN` was the result of this.

I have also tried the above using `parseFloat()` which yielded the same unfortunate results.

I also tried (read somewhere on a blog) that adding `+` in front will force jQuery to treat the variables as integers so I did (see above for where i got `one` and `two`):

```
u_one = +one
u_two = +two
```

I am starting to think that obtaining values using `val()` prevents jQuery utilising them as anything other than strings... But I must be wrong.

Can you advise on how I can obtain these values in integer format so that I can have the result:

30.00

When the fields are added?

Preferebly whilst keeping the `<input />` and not adding another hidden `<span />` or something similar containing the number to which then I can run `text()` on.

Thanks for reading.

### NOTE

It has come to light the problem was not related to jQuery and related to the template I was making use of. Code above works as pointed out in the comments below. I have accepted one as an answer however all jQuery examples posted will work.

Comment: parseInt() should work fine. As you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/T7Dt9/

Comment: You need to move the variable declarations inside of the click method, otherwise changing the numbers in the textboxes won't change the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/T7Dt9/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way

```
$(function(){
    var one = $('#one').val();
    var two = $('#two').val();

    $('#add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var three = parseInt(one) + parseInt(two);
    alert(three);
    });
});
```

refer working demo on jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/adeshpandey/Y3xmW/

Comment: His code works, see the fiddle in my comment. Plus, moving the `parseInt()` makes no difference. Not to mention you forgot the radix parameter.

Comment: oh yes! i did not see ur comment :P

Comment: Thanks guys, my stupidity. The template wasn't pulling in any values from the database into the fields, should have noticed this sooner... *attempts to down vote own question*

Answer (score 1):

Use : `var three = parseFloat(one  +  two);`

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/T6GEn/3/)

Comment: For the third time, the OP's code works, as shown by the fiddle in my comment above.

Comment: Ya, It works but for floating value use of parseFloat is Recommended ! @j08691

Comment: And Using float is also calculate your Int also..Now up to you whatever you like to Do...@j08691

Answer (score 0):

You are completely looking at the wrong problem!

You are extracting the value before the click occurs; the value is empty-string at that point.

Comment: No, it's not. The fields have default values. See the fiddle in my comment.

Comment: Damn.  Sorry, just looked at the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

the other way

```
 $(function(){
  var one = $('#one').val();
  var two = $('#two').val();

  $('#add').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault;
   var three = parseInt(one) + parseInt(two);
   $('#three').text("Total: " +three);
  });  
});
```

HTML

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="one" value="20.00" />
    <input type="text" id="two" value="10.00" />
    <a href="#" id="add">
     Add up fields
     </a>
    <p id="three"></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your input tags to type number:

```
<input type="number" id="one" value="20.00" />
```